# clang 3.3 can compile the code with namespace in vs 2010?

Tags: c++

When I compile the program using clang 3.3  on Ubuntu system,The errors are hard to me.
      the source code is as follow:

```
          #include <iostream>
          using namespace std;
          int main()
         {
               cout<<"hello world!"
               return 0;
          }
```

The code  was programmed on   vs 2010,so the command line is:

```
 clang++ -c -g -fms-compatibility -fdelayed-template-parsing -I /home/qincai/桌面/IRSA/IRSA/IRSA/vcinclude -emit-llvm -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -Wno-bitwise-op-parentheses -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-attributes -Wno-implicit-exception-spec-mismatch -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-value -imacros macro.h -Wno-microsoft teststd.cpp -o teststd.o
```

`vcinclude` is the directory of vs2010 including files and copide from windows system.
The errors are as follow:

```
    (1)ios:13:1: error: expected member
      name or ';' after declaration specifiers
_STD_BEGIN
^~~~~~~~~~
/home/qincai/桌面/IRSA/IRSA/IRSA/vcinclude/yvals.h:488:22: note: expanded from
      macro '_STD_BEGIN'
  #define _STD_BEGIN    namespace std {
                        ^~~~~~~~~
```

Is it to say that clang can not compile namespace in vc ++?
IF clang can compile the namespace, how to deal with it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a preview window on the "Ask question" page. You should use it to make sure your question is formatted properly. The original was a mess. nos pretty much fixed if for you, but please pay attention to it next time.

Comment: Are you saying you copied over the system header files for the Visual Studio compiler over to Ubuntu ? don't do that, the header files shipped by one particular compiler is not guaranteed, and usually quite unlikely, to work with a different compiler.

Comment: @nos I think you should elaborate this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your own C++ code is portable as long as you write standard C++, the header files for the C++ standard library shipped by one particular compiler is not guaranteed, and almost never are, to be portable to another compiler.

You can't use the header files of visual studio 2010 together with clang on Ubuntu.

Your code is also missing a `;` at the end of `cout<<"hello world!"`